# Merging two data sets in order to add default values for missing data

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I'm trying to merge two datasets in order to insert default rows for missing data. The use case is that I have a list of dates and attendance numbers for training sessions on those dates, but if I have no records at all for a training session then it's missing from the list.

In my sheet at the moment I have a two column set of dates and attendance numbers, and in another sheet I have worked out all the Wednesdays and Fridays (training days) between the start and end dates of all the sessions we have data for.

Is there a way to merge the two datasets together so that the zero attendance for each session is the base set and then I merge in the rows for which I have data? I've tried using some of the query command but if I specify two datasets using {Sheet1!A1:A,Sheet2!B1:B} I get array errors.

The attendance information is currently gathered with a query like this:

`=QUERY({Records!A2:B}, "SELECT Col1, COUNT(Col2) WHERE (Col1 IS NOT NULL) GROUP BY Col1 ORDER BY Col1 ASC LABEL Col1 'Session Date', COUNT(Col2) 'Skaters'")` where the Records sheets is just date and names.

If I update it to read from two datasets `(=QUERY({Records!A2:B, Scratch!B2:B}, "SELECT Col1, COUNT(Col2) WHERE (Col1 IS NOT NULL) GROUP BY Col1 ORDER BY Col1 ASC LABEL Col1 'Session Date', COUNT(Col2) 'Skaters'")`then I get a REF error of `Function ARRAY_ROW parameter 2 has mismatched row size. Expected: 982. Actual: 999`. Seems fair, as it's created misaligned dataset, rather than merging based on the date column.

I'm probably treating the spreadsheet a bit too much like a database, and while I would be more comfortable dropping into the script editor to resolve this I'm trying to learn a few spreadsheet techniques.

**Data**

Records looks like this:

`| 2018-05-04 | Bob  |
| 2018-05-04 | Fred |
| 2018-05-12 | Bob  |`

So no-one took attendance on the 9th, and so the stats are skewed as Bob gets a misleading 100% attendance record.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get that. The records sheet only has rows from Wednesdays and Friday so the selected data should be good. Are you meaning a subquery that just generates the data?

Comment: I think that's what I've been trying with the attempt to read from two datasets, but since they're mismatched in size I get that error. Perhaps I need to search for unioning in Sheets Queries. That word just came back to me!

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand the details of what you are trying to do but since it seems to involve combining one list of just dates and at least two lists of dates and names offer the following example:

[image: SO50269101 example]

The formula is:

```
=ArrayFormula(query({Sheet1!B1:C20;Sheet2!E1:F20;Sheet3!I1:J20},"select * where Col2 is not NULL order by Col1 "))
```